# How to remove Messenger Icon from Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I Action Bar i am using ShareActionProvider, but facing small issue, i am also getting Messenger Icon along with Share Icon, and i don't want to show Messenger Icon in my Action Bar.

So how can i remove Messenger Icon from Action Bar, see my code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);      
         mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share).getActionProvider();
         if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
         mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());
         }
         return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJECT");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "TEXT");
        return intent;
    }
```

I just want to show Share Icon in my Action Bar not Messenger Icon...

see screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are welcome to try `setShareHistoryFileName(null)` and see if that blocks the second icon along with the history.

Otherwise, you will need to write your own action provider as a replacement for `ShareActionProvider`. Or, you will need to attempt to fork `ShareActionProvider` to block this second icon.

Answer (score 0):

Create a menu in layout in this way:

```
<item
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/share_icon"/>
```

When you click on it you can show the default sharing sources.